# Preload page placeholder jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery

I found a js file that you can include on top of a page to display "loading" placeholder box while the page is loading. The problem is that if I have other elements on a page, like chart, that take longer to load, the page will stop showing this placeholder even if the chart is not loaded yet. Is there a way to modify this code to keep this placeholder until 100% of the page, including all elements, loads. Similar to the browser that shows load progress untill all is loaded.

Here's the code for this JS file:

```
var jQueryLoaderOptions = null;
(function(a) {
    a.loader = function(d) {
        switch (d) {
        case "close":
            if (jQueryLoaderOptions) {
                if (a("#" + jQueryLoaderOptions.id)) {
                    a("#" + jQueryLoaderOptions.id + ", #" + jQueryLoaderOptions.background.id).remove()
                }
            }
            return;
            break;
        case "setContent":
            if (jQueryLoaderOptions) {
                if (a("#" + jQueryLoaderOptions.id)) {
                    if (a.loader.arguments.length == 2) {
                        a("#" + jQueryLoaderOptions.id).html(a.loader.arguments[1])
                    } else {
                        if (console) {
                            console.error("setContent method must have 2 arguments $.loader('setContent', 'new content');")
                        } else {
                            alert("setContent method must have 2 arguments $.loader('setContent', 'new content');")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return;
            break;
        default:
            var b = a.extend({
                content: "<div>Loading ...</div>",
                className: "loader",
                id: "jquery-loader",
                height: 70,
                width: 70,
                zIndex: 30000,
                background: {
                    opacity: 0.4,
                    id: "jquery-loader-background"
                }
            }, d)
        }
        jQueryLoaderOptions = b;
        var c = a(document).height();
        var e = a(window).width();
        var g = a('<div id="' + b.background.id + '"/>');
        g.css({
            zIndex: b.zIndex,
            position: "absolute",
            top: "0px",
            left: "0px",
            width: e,
            height: c,
            opacity: b.background.opacity
        });
        g.appendTo("body");
        if (jQuery.bgiframe) {
            g.bgiframe()
        }
        var f = a('<div id="' + b.id + '" class="' + b.className + '"></div>');
        f.css({
            zIndex: b.zIndex + 1,
            width: b.width,
            height: b.height
        });
        f.appendTo("body");
        f.center();
        a(b.content).appendTo(f)
    };
    a.fn.center = function() {
        this.css("position", "absolute");
        this.css("top", (a(window).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2 + a(window).scrollTop() + "px");
        this.css("left", (a(window).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2 + a(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
        return this
    }
})(jQuery);
```

and call it like this:

```
$(".preloader").click(function(){ $.loader({ className:"ajLoad", content:"" }); });
```

Comment: what about to intend your code?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. I need the placeholder to display until all elements on the page are 100% loaded...

Comment: I think the loading progress shown is different across browsers. For example, some browser (e.g. Safari) would show loading progress for AJAX calls (e.g. background loading), whereas Firefox doesn't. So, it comes down to what elements do you want your loading progress to show.

Comment: Your interpretation of document ready may be a bit off...Document ready occurs when all nodes have been inserted into the DOM.  Images may not be done loading, ajax calls may not have be done, and any JS that you have running in the document ready function, will not have occurred yet.  If you are loading charts via JS in the document ready function, you will need to handle your loading screen through more complex JS signal handling

Answer (score 1):

The plugin you're using probably just waits for the document.ready function. You'd have to modify it to listen for a custom event you fire and make sure your code fires it on either document.ready or when your the last element on the page is loaded.

This would work, but would be kind of complicated as then you would need code to make sure things are loaded on the page.

Comment: So document.ready is true even if not all elements are loaded? What does the browser look at when displaying the progress? Can I do something similar to it?

Comment: Can it be modified by adding an extra parameter, which could be set to null by default or wait for a particular element (by id name) if ID is provided?

Comment: document.ready is looking for DOM readiness, not to make sure that async scripts have all loaded. Assuming that your thing loads data async from the rest of site. 

Modify document.ready? I wouldn't modify jQuery if you are using it :/

Comment: At the moment i have this loader and then the page loads, but sometimes if the elements are loading from a db, for example, they load after the page loads, sort of defeats the purpose...

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to modify this code to keep this placeholder until
>   100% of the page, including all elements, loads. Similar to the
>   browser that shows load progress untill all is loaded.

you can use load statement reference to its window, something like...

```
$(window).load(function() {
   // put your code here...

});
// NB : put this code before your </head>
```

Comment: Which part of code shall I put? Just this one? $.loader({ className:"ajLoad", content:"" });

Comment: That would work unless he has some elements of the page in flash (or silverlight) for example. *Load* event would fire even if the flash elements are not done loading yet. Solution would be to use externalInterface of flash and signal don't hide the placeholder unless flash has signaled that it is done loading.

Comment: @WTK, look at his original question. It didnt mention anything about flash or silverlight resources.

Comment: Yeah, but he did mentioned *"other elements on a page, like chart"*. If there are any resources fetched with ajax than your resolution wouldn't work as expected as well. That doesn't mean that your solution is bad, I'm simply pointing out, that it can be unreliable in some scenarios.